# How should I set PATH when using rbenv with bundler and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rbenv

I'm venturing back into Ruby and Rails and giving rbenv a try at the same time.  I'm on a Mac (10.14) if that matters.  I'm using

- Bundler version 2.0.1
- Rails 6.0.0.rc1
- ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin18]
- rbenv 1.1.2

My `~/.bundle/config` file has:

```
 ----
 BUNDLE_PATH: ".bundle/gems"
 BUNDLE_BIN: ".bundle/bin"
 BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: "true"
 BUNDLE_CACHE_PATH: "/Users/xxx/.bundle/cache"
 BUNDLE_CACHE_ALL: "true"
```

I do a simple `rails init foo` followed by `cd foo` and I find that I have three bin directories of interest:

- .bundle/bin
- .bundle/gems/bin
- bin

My normal path has `/Users/xxx/.rbenv/shims` at the front.  If I do `type rake` or `type rails` I get the one in the shims directory such as `/Users/xxx/.rbenv/shims/rake`

My question is: should I put one of the three bin directories listed above into my PATH and if so, which ones and which order?

My belief is that the correct thing to do is to add the full path to the `.bundle/bin` directory followed by the full path to the `bin` directory followed by my usual PATH.  Is that correct?